# How to get my 24 word seed using bitcoin-cli

Tags: mnemonic-seed, seed

I've tried:
bitcoin-cli sethdseed 'word1 word2 ...'
but i got invalid private key.
please help me getting my 24 word seed using bitcoin core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **How to get my 24 word seed using bitcoin-cli**

You write about *getting* but your commands are about *setting*. This is confusing.

You can't **get** a seed-phrase from Bitcoin-core.

You can use the [sethdseed](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/sethdseed/) function to *"Set or generate a new HD wallet seed."* this marks any existing private keys as inactive (which may or may not be what you want).

Note that an `HD seed` and a (24 word) `seed phrase` are different things.

---

> **I've tried: bitcoin-cli sethdseed 'word1 word2 ...' but i got invalid private key.**

I think that may be because the second argument is not a seed phrase but a [WIF](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) key.

> 2. "seed"               (string, optional) The WIF private key to use as the new HD seed;

---

Related questions with useful answers (assuming you're trying to get seed-words out of Bitcoin Core because you think thats whats needed to transfer to another wallet that uses them)

- [How can I transfer a Bitcoin-qt wallet to Electrum?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12763/13866)
- [How To Transfer Coins From Bitcoin Core to Electrum to avoid Sync Process?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74031/13866)
- [Having trouble transfering private keys from Bitcoin Core to Electrum, for want of not having to wait for sync](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/88195/13866)

Comment: Sorry Asking dumb questions but how can i convert my hdseed to a mnemonic phrase.

Comment: @Erfan. There's no need. Instead people changing from Bitcoin core to another wallet usually export the private key and tell the new wallet to sweep the key.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Bitcoin Core is not BIP39 compliant.

Comment: To note, this is not a bad thing. Bitcoin Core is also not compliant with regulations on PPE, but that doesn't not taint it as a software product.

Comment: One still get and store the hd seed key of a wallet in it's WIF encoding. Use `dumpwallet` and then check the file for `hdseed=1`.